# Is it possible to replace the default back button and sidebar icon in iPad's Navigation Bar using NavigationView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, ios-navigationview

I'm trying to make an iOS app that uses SwiftUI's `NavigationView` to build a side menu.
On iPhone it works perfectly, but on iPad I cannot get Rid of the Sidebar button and the back button text and icon. I would like to replace those buttons with the three horizontal lines icon named `line.horizontal.3`

[Landscape screenshot with side menu icon I'd like to replace with three lines icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj0Vc.png)

[Portrait screenshot with back button (woth icon and text) I'd like to replace with three lines icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2pVd.png)

The code I'm using is the following:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView_iPad: View {
    @State var showMenu: Bool = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            MenuView()
            iPad_menu()
                .navigationBarTitle("Side Menu", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                        (Button(action: {
                                            withAnimation{
                                                self.showMenu.toggle()
                                            }
                                        }){
                                            Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3").imageScale(.large)
                                        }
                                        ))
                .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }
        
    }
}
```

The MainView:

```
import SwiftUI
    
struct iPad_menu: View {
        var body: some View {
            EmptyView()
                .background(Color.black)
        }
    }
```

The MenuView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MenuView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "person")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .imageScale(.large)
                        Text("Profile")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                        .padding(.top, 100)
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "envelope")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .imageScale(.large)
                        Text("Messages")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                        .padding(.top, 30)
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "gear")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .imageScale(.large)
                        Text("Settings")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                        .padding(.top, 30)
                }
        .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .background(Color(red: 32/255, green: 32/255, blue: 32/255))
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```